# How to only create a PR for matchedDependencies with Renovate

Tags: renovate

I want to only create a Pull Request for the below specified dependencies. All other dependencies should not be considered. The config below does not do that because I get separate PR's for all dependencies that do not match the rules I specified. For example I get a PR for SimpleInjector.
How can I get one PR only for the Dependencies that match, but no other PR's at all without creating explicit exclusion rules for every dependency?

```
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchPackagePatterns": [
        "System.*",
      ],
      "excludePackageNames": ["Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers"],
      "matchUpdateTypes": [
        "minor",
        "patch"
      ],
      "groupName": "non major",
      "groupSlug": "non-major"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to know that were key to solve this problem:

- Rules get evaluated from top to bottom
- All dependencies get updated by default

The config below disables all dependencies first and then selectively enables some dependencies again:

```
"packageRules": [
    {
      "matchPackagePatterns": ["*"],
      "enabled": false
    },
    {
      "matchPackagePatterns": [
        "System.*",
      ],
      "enabled": true
    },
    {
      "matchUpdateTypes": [
        "minor",
        "patch"
      ],
      "groupSlug": "non-major"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#packagerules

>Important to know: Renovate will evaluate all packageRules and not stop once it gets a >first match. You should order your packageRules in ascending order of importance so that >more important rules come later and can override settings from earlier rules if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Read here: https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#packagerules

> Important to know: Renovate will evaluate all packageRules and not stop once it gets a first match. You should order your packageRules in ascending order of importance so that more important rules come later and can override settings from earlier rules if needed.

[image]